# Visual Studio NodeJS Tools - How to Package Project? Create NPM?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript, npm

I've got a VS2013 solution with a mix of NodeJS (using TypeScript) and C# class library projects (they're bound together by EdgeJS).  Where the NodeJS projects are concerned, one can be considered a library (for a RabbitMQ bus implementation), two are applications which are meant to be hosted as part of a fourth project with both using the bus.

So, one project (***host***) which will depend on three projects (***bus***, ***app1*** and ***app2***) (it starts the ***bus***, and passes it to ***app1*** and ***app2***).

Of course, I could just lump all these projects together and be done with it - but that's a horrible idea.

How do I package these projects up for proper reuse and referencing (like assemblies in traditional .NET)?

Is that best done with NPM?  If so, does VS provide anything in this area?  If not, then what?

Note that, aside from the Bus project, I'm not looking to release these publicly - I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if something can be bundled together as an independent library, then it's best to consider this a Node package and thus, refactor that logic out to it's own project.  It sounds like you've already done this to some extent, separating out your `bus`, `app1`, and `app2` projects.  I would recommend they each have their own Git repositories if they are separate packages.

Here's some documentation to get you started with Node packages:
https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html

The `host` project, if it's not something you would package but instead deploy, probably does not need to be bundled as a Node package.  I would instead just consider this something that would be pulled down from Git and started on some server machine.

With all that said, your last line is important:

> I'm not looking to release these publicly

GitHub does have private repositories, but as of now npmjs.org does not have private repositories.  There are options to create your own private repository ([Sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) and [Kappa](https://github.com/krakenjs/kappa) offer different ways of accomplishing this), but if you don't want this code available for everyone do not deploy it do npmjs.org.  You can still package it up in the way I've outlined it above, just not deploy it as of yet.